# XML to Azure ML Studio

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, machine-learning-model, ml-studio

i try to test ML Studio with some data stored in XML. However i tried a lot of things i.e. convert xml to csv, to JSON but didn't find a good way to use ML studio with this data.

The problem is not the conversion itself, It's just a problem of the semi structuring. In my opinion there should be a solution like using a CSV file as an array of data or like this.

What would be the best way to use XML in ML studio?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to add a XML file to Azure ML Studio.

1. Add the XML file to a Azure SQL database and import the data through 'import data' module.
2. Convert the XML file to CSV file and upload it as a dataset.
3. Convert the XML file to CSV file store in a Azure Blob storage. It can be retrieved from 'import data' module.

There's no direct way in ML Studio to convert a XML for CSV/TSV